# Setting the source number on nodejs with Plivo

Tags: node.js, plivo

If i want make a call using the Plivo API i need to have a source number and destination number. However, the source number has to be linked with my Plivo account. But when reading their tutorials, they mentioned that buying a Plivo number is optional and only needed if you want to receive calls. I only want to sent calls. Anyone know how to make a call with free account using Plivo in nodejs?

```
var params = {
    'to': '2222222222', // The phone numer to which the all has to be placed
    'from' : '1111111111', // The phone number to be used as the caller id
    'answer_url' : "https://some-url/speak.xml", // The URL invoked by Plivo when the outbound call is answered
    'answer_method' : "GET", // The method used to call the answer_url
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you could use any number as source. Like it doesn't have to be registered. So, `'from' : '1111111111'` would actually work.